# How to compare Dev and Prod Azure Data Factory implementation?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I might have modified Data Factory pipeline implemented by another developer in accident.
But don't know now that what was modified since there were so many modification.

Is there any tool to compare what is difference between development and prod environment to see how they differ from each others?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the code from the pipeline from 2 versions and compare them using comparison tools available online for free.

[image]

You can also go through this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.datafactory/?view=azps-7.3.0) to use the PowerShell cmdlets to get the information of the pipelines in the Azure data factory.